# Liferay - Call a controller of a remote portlet

Tags: java, spring, liferay

I was trying to call a controller of a portlet belonging to a remote portal.
I tried following [this](https://www.liferay.com/web/vitor.silva/blog/-/blogs/using-restful-services-with-liferay) tutorial but it is has a lot of extra stuffs which are causing build errors for me.

I have a controller like below in the remote portlet.

```
@Controller
public class SampleRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody String helloSample() {
        return "Finally!";
    }
}
```

What should I do in order to call the above method using a rest call..? That is, what are the changes I should make to a basic spring liferay portlet to get the output of `http://localhost:port/.../.../helloSample` as `Finally!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a rest controller working inside a portlet. The linked article [Using RESTFul services with Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/web/vitor.silva/blog/-/blogs/using-restful-services-with-liferay) explains it nicely. Here's just the summary.

**Custom servlet inside a portlet**

What you need to do is to implement a servlet wrapped in a portlet application. You need to configure Liferay's [`PortalDelegateServlet`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/PortalDelegateServlet.java) in web.xml. The servlet will delegate request processing to Spring's `DispatcherServlet`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
        <param-value>restful</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
<servlet-mapping>
```

The restful servlet needs its separate application context that will contain `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, view resolver and JSON mapper.

Given the rest controller from your example

```
@Controller
public class SampleRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody String helloSample() {
        return "Finally!";
    }
}
```

The resulting url is composed followingly

```
http://host:port/<<context path>>/services/helloSample
                 |                |        |
                 | Context path of your application (eg. test-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
                                  |        |
                                  | Defined by servlet mapping in web.xml
                                           |
                                           | Defined by @RequestMapping in the controller
```

Sample url for Tomcat deployment: http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/services/helloSample

See [the linked article](https://www.liferay.com/web/vitor.silva/blog/-/blogs/using-restful-services-with-liferay) for more details.

The original idea for this feature is summarized in Liferay JIRA issue [Custom servlets running in the ROOT context](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LEP-2297).

Comment: I tried to implement that. But I am still not successful. I see the message `[RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181] Mapped "{[/helloSample],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.liferay.test.servlet.SampleRestController.helloSample()` . But when I try to access using the url you provided above, it says `Not Found`

Comment: Can you please verify https://github.com/philipjohn007/Test-Portlet and let me know what mistake I am doing in my code please..? I did not add the section for `jacksonObjectMapper` in `test-servlet` as I was getting class not found exception for this mapper. Is that causing the issue..?

Comment: The example is very good and almost working. You need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller method. Otherwise, the result is interpreted as JSP view name. And I corrected the url description - it doesn't contain portlet name (as I wrote initially), but of course the context path of the application (in my case with Tomcat - http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/services/helloSample ). That's all I needed to make the test application working. You can return `PortalUtil.getPortal()` in `helloSample` method to verify the JSON mapper works (it does).

Answer (score 0):

Because your controller does *not* belong to a portlet, you can simply call

```
http://localhost:port/_context path of your war_/helloSample
```

As the linked tutorial says:

> So in my sample project I will produce RESTFul services that will be consumed by custom portlets...

He did not create a portlet that contains the controller - neither do you.